# Override save method to add list in the many to many field

Tags: django, django-models

I have this model to save post from the users:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

def add_tags(obj_id, body):
    object = Post.objects.get(id=obj_id)
    tag_list = [Tag.objects.create(name=word) for word in body.split()]
    for tag in tag_list:
        object.tags.add(tag)

class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    body = models.TextField()
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    activity = GenericRelation(Activity, related_query_name="posts")

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.body:
            body = self.body
            obj_id = self.id
            add_tags(obj_id, body)
```

So whenever a user post something, I would like to check if there's any hash-tag used inside the body. If there are tags, then fetch the tags inside the list.

But when I am posting, the tag objects are created, but they are not adding for the Post.tags fields.

post.body example = *Check #from the http://somesitedotcom/page#idtop #hell yeah!*

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Pro-tip: you don't need to add [please help me](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2634889+please+help+me) or similar to all of your questions. It is clear you want help, so filler material of this kind may be interpreted as begging, and it is often trimmed by editors anyway.

Comment: @halfer Ok, got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common mistake made by people. In order to update a model object's m2m relationship, the object needs to be saved in database first. Django m2m is essentially using an intermediate table to store the relationship, so without both ends saved, the relationship cannot be formed.

I wouldn't rely on overriding `save()` method to achieve this, but rather deal with this process separately in views method, because `save()` can happen in any situation, but you might not always what this process to happen. For the sake of correctness, you should do it after you call `super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)` in the `save` method.

**Edit:**

Sounds like your code is also buggy. `tag_list` is a list of strings, but your code `self.tags.add(*tag_list)` treated them as `Tag` objects. You need to create `Tag` objects then use `add` to link the relationship.

Comment: Ok, So I changed the save() method. But I am getting this error: `invalid literal for int() with base 10: '#hell'`

Comment: I edited my answer to address your issue. See if it makes sense.

Comment: Again, I edited my answer to address your issue. See if it makes sense.

Comment: Ooh... yes. This might be the problem. I will confirm and come back.

Comment: So I have changed the code a bit to save the Post object first and then create tags from the Post body, and then add it in Post object. But its not adding. Will you please have a look at the updated code.

Comment: There could be a million possibilities that the code could go wrong, without being in your environment I couldn't guess what goes wrong. Maybe your `tag_list` is totally empty, but you need to debug this. Either print out some variables or use `pdb` to set a break point.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t associate `Post` with a `tag` until it’s been saved:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.body:
        tag_list = [word for word in self.body.split() if word.startswith("#")]
        self.body = tag_list
        self.tags.add(*tag_list)
```

Comment: Yes, I am not getting the previous error now. But instead I am getting this error: `invalid literal for int() with base 10: '#hell'`